# Не работает pyttsx3. Не выдаёт ошибок, просто молчит

Tags: python, pyttsx3

Написал код в PyCharm. Ошибок не выдаёт. Просто молчит. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()

engine.setProperty('rate', 150)
engine.setProperty('volume', 0.9)

engine.say('I can speak!')
engine.say('Я могу говорить!')

engine.runAndWait()
```

Пробовал искать в интернете. Наверное плохо искал, потому-что ничего не помогло.

Comment: Попробовал запустить, работает, балаболет. на двух языках.